# How can I login to Amazon EC2 without using PEM file?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Cause i want to access my own EC2 from different host. It is hard to key the pem file in every host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SSH access:

```
# Turn on password authentication
sudo sed -i 's/^PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Reload SSHd configuration
sudo service sshd reload
# Set a password for the ec2-user
sudo passwd ec2-user
```

Comment: It is almost correct. but when i try to set passwd for ec2-user. 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error. It seems that we don't have the default password that amazon gave up...

Comment: Perhaps changing it as root!  Updated answer.